# NullPointerException Java BFS

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am trying to perform a Breath First Search on a graph that I am creating from an adjacency list from a text file "Input.txt" I am getting a NullPointerException on line 162 where it says "root.visited = true;" I cannot figure out why this is. Here is what code i have.

```
     import java.io.BufferedReader;
     import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
     import java.io.FileReader;
     import java.io.IOException;
     import java.util.ArrayList;
     import java.util.Iterator;
     import java.util.LinkedList;
     import java.util.Queue;
     import java.util.Stack;

    public class BFS {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        {
            Graph g = new Graph();
            // Making Adjacency Matrix
            ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> adjacency = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
            adjacency.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());

            String input = "input.txt";
            Graph MyGraph = new Graph();
            boolean root = true;
            Vertex n = null;
            int j = 0;
            try {
                // Reading in the Input File to the Adjacency Matrix
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new FileReader(input));
                String line = reader.readLine();

                while (line != null) {
                    // Getting numbers from each line
                    String[] numbers = line.split(",");
                    int[] values = new int[numbers.length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
                        values[i] += Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);

                    // Adding values to Matrix
                    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                        adjacency.get(j).add(values[i]);
                        System.out.print(" " + adjacency.get(j).get(i)); // output
                                                                            // of
                                                                            // matrix
                    }
                    System.out.print("\n");

                    // Progressing through file
                    adjacency.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
                    line = reader.readLine();
                    j++;
                }

                // read each line
                for (int currRow = 0; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; currRow++) {
                    String[] row = line.split(",");

                    // insert vertices
                    if (currRow == 0) {

                        for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
                            g.addVertex(n);
                            if (root = true) {

                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // create the edges specified in this row
                    for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {

                        // edge exists between indices 'currRow' and col 'i'.
                        if (Integer.parseInt(row[i]) == 1) {
                            g.connectVertex(currRow, i);
                        }
                    }
                }
                reader.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

            /* DFS Algorithm */

            // schtuff (use stack? use index of node for unique number?)

            // System.out.print("Visited nodes (in order): ");

        }

        // catch exceptions & errors
        Graph MyGraph = new Graph();
        MyGraph.dfs();
    }

    public static class Graph {
        public Vertex root;
        public ArrayList<Vertex> vertices = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        public ArrayList<Vertex> dfsArrList = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        public int[][] adjMatrix;
        int size;

        public void setRootVertex(Vertex n) {
            this.root = n;
        }

        public Vertex getRootVertex() {
            return this.root;
        }

        public void addVertex(Vertex n) {
            vertices.add(n);
        }

        public void removeVertex(int loc) {
            vertices.remove(loc);
        }

        public void connectVertex(int vertexStart, int vertexEnd) {
            if (adjMatrix == null) {
                size = vertices.size();
                adjMatrix = new int[size][size];
            }

            int startIndex = vertices.indexOf(vertexStart) + 1;
            int endIndex = vertices.indexOf(vertexEnd) + 1;
            adjMatrix[startIndex][endIndex] = 1;
            adjMatrix[endIndex][startIndex] = 1;
        }

        public void removeEdge(Vertex v1, Vertex v2) {

            int startIndex = vertices.indexOf(v1);
            int endIndex = vertices.indexOf(v2);
            adjMatrix[startIndex][endIndex] = 1;
            adjMatrix[endIndex][startIndex] = 1;
        }

        public int countVertices() {
            int ver = vertices.size();
            return ver;
        }

        private Vertex getUnvisitedChildNode(Vertex n) {

            int index = vertices.indexOf(n);
            int j = 0;
            while (j < size) {
                if (adjMatrix[index][j] == 1
                        && vertices.get(j).visited == false) {
                    return vertices.get(j);
                }
                j++;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public Iterator<Vertex> dfs() {

            Stack<Vertex> s = new Stack<Vertex>();
            s.push(this.root);
            root.visited = true;
            printVertex(root);
            while (!s.isEmpty()) {
                Vertex n = s.peek();
                Vertex child = getUnvisitedChildNode(n);
                if (child != null) {
                    child.visited = true;
                    dfsArrList.add(child);
                    s.push(child);
                } else {
                    s.pop();
                }
            }
            clearVertices();
            return dfsArrList.iterator();
        }

        private void clearVertices() {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < size) {
                Vertex n = vertices.get(i);
                n.visited = false;
                i++;
            }
        }

        private void printVertex(Vertex n) {
            System.out.print(n.vertexName + " ");
        }
    }

    public class Vertex {

        public char vertexName;
        public boolean visited = false;

        public Vertex(char l) {
            this.vertexName = l;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: And where is the exception stack trace ? Provide only relevant code

Comment: First thing to make it easier to track down changes to your variables: make them private. Why would you bother with setters and getters at all while almost all your variables are public? Next: you never appear to be calling setRootVertex...

Comment: Oh wow yea i never called setRootVertex. If i wanted to set the root to the first vertex in my adjacency matrix how would i do so?

Comment: @Cfox7: As I've said in my answer, I suggest you start off by restructuring the code entirely. That should make it easier to work with. Then once you've got code you can understand, start making changes to what you're actually doing - and ask a question about *that*.

Comment: You shouldn't have a boolean **and** a vertex called `root` (even if you can). In this case I think the boolean should change names.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this code (which is slightly bizarrely after a braced section of `main`):

```
Graph MyGraph = new Graph();
MyGraph.dfs();
```

The `dfs` method starts with:

```
Stack<Vertex> s = new Stack<Vertex>();
s.push(this.root);
root.visited = true;
```

What do you expect `MyGraph.root` to be here? How could it be anything other than null? (Note that you've got two `MyGraph` variables declared in `main`. The first one isn't used for anything, for some reason.)

I strongly suggest you restructure this code significantly:

- Refactor your `main` method to be smaller
- Avoid introducing a new scope just for the sake of it - the fact that your main method is effectively:

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
      {
           // Code
      }
  }
  ```

  is very odd.
- Avoid nested classes when you don't really need them: use separate files
- Avoid public variables
- Make your data immutable where you can. Do you really need to change the root of a vertex *after* construction? Couldn't you pass it to a constructor? Things like this make the code easier to understand.

Comment: I Like your speed in answering with details.

Comment: At the moment I just want to be able to set Vertex "n" to something other than "Null" I'd like to be able to set it to the first vertex in the adjacency list here http://pastebin.com/5a0vbEjy

Comment: Another fine answer indeed Jon.

Answer (score 0):

`Vertex root` is not initialized so `root.visited` becomes `null.visited` at runtime which cause `NullPointerException`.

`Vertex root` is expected to set the value by `setRootVertex` method.

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke 
    MyGraph.dfs(); 
    public static class Graph { 
        public Vertex root;

Your root is not initialized.